# How to get the ajax start event and stop event

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have many ajax requests in my application. I am using jquery ajaxStart and ajaxStop in my application to show loading symbol. But they are not working. I googled out but did not find correct solution. I am using like this

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  Actions.showLoading("Loading");
});
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
  Actions.hideLoading();
});
```

Comment: Looks about right, did you check the console for errors, and do those functions work like they should.

Comment: I added console logs also to check whether it is going to those functions or not. They are going but not working!

Answer (score 0):

> jQuery
>
> > If $.ajax() or $.ajaxSetup() is called with the global option set to false, the .ajaxStart() method will not fire.

check your code & try again.

Comment: No I am not using them

Comment: $( document ).ajaxStart(function() { 
  console.log('fired');
  Actions.showLoading("Loading");
}); 
try this whether this firing or not?

Comment: then the issue is inside **Actions.showLoading("Loading")** function, you have to fix that

Comment: If I am using this out side the ajaxStart function it is working fine

Comment: may be its using call contexts, which library you are using for this Actions.showLoading function, if possible paste that function here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43844/discussion-between-anwar-javed-and-bala-subramanyam)